# Hibernate @Filter annotation usage

Tags: java, hibernate

Currently I am using Hibernate 3.2 **@Filter** feature along with JPA so everything goes through entity manager. My question this use case:

Suppose we have annotated entity class **A** with **@Filter(name="filterOne")**
Now suppose that entity class **A** is a composition of entity class **B**

**B** <>---- listOfA - List::A ---- **A** (fetch type is eager)

Now **B.listOfA** (attribute) is annotated with **@Filter(name="filterTwo")**

Will hibernate apply **filterOne** and **filterTwo** if I query for entity **B** and get **listOfA** ?

Comment: Did you try it? What was the outcome?

Answer (score 1):

No, the filters are **not** applied to to-many associations if they are defined at the target entity level only and, by the way, they are **never** applied on to-one associations.

You have to explicitly define the filter at the collection level as well.

Comment: Could you provide links to documentation that supports this?